# Connection Angular to Node/express in a Vagrant box

Tags: node.js, angular, vagrant

I have an Angular server and a separate Node/Express server running inside the same Vagrant Ubuntu machine. I am following [this](https://www.udemy.com/course/angular-2-and-nodejs-the-practical-guide/) course. The reason why I am moving over to a separate machine is because I am having issues with my Windows operating system running the MongoDB client to connect to the database on Mongo atlas, and because I am more used to Unix/Linux development (my other machine, a Mac Mini I bought 4 years ago is not too slow for my taste).

This is my Vagrantfile

```
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 # Running standard Ubuntu 64 bits version
 config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
 # Open ports for Node.js and MongoDB
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3333 # Node.js
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017 # MongoDB
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4200, host: 4200 # 
 # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
 # using a specific IP.
 config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
 # Set up a synced folder/
 config.vm.synced_folder "D:/Code/mean-apps", "/project"
 # Provision VM only once
 config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision.sh"
end
```

this is my server.js file provided from the course

```
    const app = require("./backend/app");
const debug = require("debug")("node-angular");
const http = require("http");

const normalizePort = val => {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
};

const onError = error => {
  if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
    throw error;
  }
  const bind = typeof port === "stri`ng" ? "pipe " + port : "port " + port;
  switch (error.code) {
    case "EACCES":
      console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case "EADDRINUSE":
      console.error(bind + " is already in use");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
};

const onListening = () => {
  const addr = server.address();
  const bind = typeof port === "string" ? "pipe " + port : "port " + port;
  debug("Listening on " + bind);
};

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set("port", port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.on("error", onError);
server.on("listening", onListening);
server.listen(port);
```

and this the the Angular service in where I connect the Angular and Node servers

```
        import { Post } from './posts.model';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { stringify } from 'querystring';
    @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
    export class PostsService {
       private posts: Post[] = [];
       private postsUpdated = new Subject<Post[]>();

       constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

       }


       getPosts() {
        this.http.get<{message: string, posts: Post[]}>("http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/posts").subscribe((postData) => {
           this.posts =  postData.posts;
           this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);

        });

        }

        getPostsUpdateListner() {
            return this.postsUpdated.asObservable();
        }

       addPost(title: string, content: string) {
           const post: Post = {id: null, title: title, content: content}
           this.http.post<{message: string}>('http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/posts', post).subscribe((responseData) => {
            this.posts.push(post);
            this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);


       })

   }
}
```

This is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Post = require('./models/post');
const app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://postproject:ChXhfaHz60e4XIm8@cluster0-a1blo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to database!');
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('COnnection failed!');
    });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 
    'Origin, X-Request-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});
//
app.post('/api/posts', (req, res, next) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content
    });
    post.save();
    console.log(post);
    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Post added sucessfully'
    });
});

app.use('/api/posts', (req, res, next) => {
    const posts = [
        { 'id': 'dsfdg', 'title': 'Post title from Express', 'content': 'This is coming from the server'},

        { 'id': 'gfhjtfgh', 'title': 'Second title from Express', 'content': 'ZThis is coming from the server again'},

        { 'id': 'dsfgfhdg', 'title': 'Third title from Express', 'content': 'ZThis is coming from the server yet again'},

    ];
 res.status(200).json({
     message: 'Posts fetched successfully',
    posts: posts
 });

});


module.exports = app;
```

As it stands right now, when I open http://192.168.10.33:4200, the post in the api do not appear in the list (I see my No posts yet message) so Angular is not loading my API.

If I have to I will use my slower machine but as I do all my day-to-day work on my Windows machine, I prefer to do things this way.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot Angular runs in the browser. Stupid mistake on my end

Since Angular runs on the host machine, my service should look like this:

```
import { Post } from './posts.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PostsService {
   private posts: Post[] = [];
   private postsUpdated = new Subject<Post[]>();

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

   }


   getPosts() {
    this.http.get<{message: string, posts: Post[]}>("http://192.168.33.10:3000/api/posts").subscribe((postData) => {
       this.posts =  postData.posts;
       this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);

    });

    }

    getPostsUpdateListner() {
        return this.postsUpdated.asObservable();
    }

   addPost(title: string, content: string) {
       const post: Post = {id: null, title: title, content: content}
       this.http.post<{message: string}>('http://192.168.33.10:3000/api/posts', post).subscribe((responseData) => {
        this.posts.push(post);
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);


       });

   }
}
```